# arm-linux-gnu-strip command

Tags: compiling

From Linux man pages:
arm-linux-gnu-strip command discards all symbols from object files objfile. The list of object files may include archives.

When would one use this command and for what purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symbol is just a name of a function/variable and the address of its entry point in the object file, archive (archive means static library), shared library or executable.

Executables don't need symbols, because usually nothing links to them.

The modules (plugins) may not need symbols. They are the libraries that, when loaded, execute a startup code that calls into application to give it pointers to callback function and data. But application don't call the functions from that plugin by name, so no need for symbols.

`strip` has an option to strip only debug information. So, it's a way to split the library and its debug information into separate files. And then it's usually distributed in separate packages: like `libfoo` and `libfoo-dbg`.